# Ionic Horizontal Scroll - Keeping or Bringing Selected Item into View

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I am using a horizontal scroll in my application for selecting menu categories.

I used the CodePen example [here](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/HIuft) and everything works great.

I have implemented swipe left/right to change between the categories, but if I to a category that is off the screen, I want it to be shown, not hidden to the right/left.

How can I programmatically (or through CSS) make sure that a selected item (defined by a class) is always visible on on scrolled into view?

Here is an example of what it looks like when a selected category is in view (its bolded from a CSS class)

[image]

Here is an example of the result of swiping right until a category is selected that is off screen.

[image]

The code for the horizontal scrolling bar is the following

```
    <div class="bar bar-sub-header item-input-inset">
        <ion-scroll direction="x" class="wide-as-needed">
            <button ng-repeat="category in model.selectedMenu.categories"
                ng-click="selectCategory(category)"
                ng-style="model.selectedCategory.id == category.id && {'font-weight': 'bold'}"
                class="button button-clear category">
                {{category.name | uppercase}}
            </button>
      </ion-scroll>
    </div>
```

And the CSS class used is the following:

.wide-as-needed {
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

Comment: i also facing same issue